# JSF Links not working

Tags: jsf

I have a form with an attachment.When I tried to view my document,It is doing form validation and is asking to fill the respective fields,But i don't want to validate the form to view my file.I have changed the link from hcommand link to acommand link and tried a few more.But it's not working.Can someone help me out.
My code is

```
<h:form id="mailForm">
                <span class = "clasMpnlErr" style="color:Blue"><h:messages id="mailFormErrorMessages" for="mailForm"/></span>
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 60px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.order.ordersummary.email.label.to']}"/>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="to" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.toAddressList}" style="width: 685px;margin-left: 10px;" required="true" maxlength="255">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="255"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <span class="clasFormElemErr"><h:message for="to"/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 60px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.order.ordersummary.email.label.cc']}"/>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="cc" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.ccAddressList}" style="width: 685px;margin-left: 10px;" maxlength="255">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="255"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <span class="clasFormElemErr"><h:message for="cc"/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 60px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.order.ordersummary.email.label.bcc']}"/>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="bcc" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.bccAddressList}" style="width: 685px;margin-left: 10px;" maxlength="255">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="255"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <span class="clasFormElemErr"><h:message for="bcc"/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 60px;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.order.ordersummary.email.label.subject']}"/>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="subject" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.subject}" style="width: 685px;margin-left: 10px;" maxlength="100">
                                <f:validateLength maximum="100"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <span class="clasFormElemErr"><h:message for="subject"/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&#160;</td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputTextarea readonly="true" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.contentNoComments}" rows="10" style="width: 685px;background: white;border: 0;margin-left: 10px;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                            <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.order.ordersummary.email.label.comments']}"/>:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputTextarea id="comments" value="#{action.currentEditingEmail.comments}" rows="5" style="width: 685px;margin-left: 10px;" />
                            <span class="clasFormElemErr"><h:message for="comments"/></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>                            
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom">
                            <int:status id="editingEmailStatus" />                                                                                      
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
                <h:commandButton id="previousEmailLink" action="#{action.previousEmail}" style="visibility:hidden;display: none;">
                    <a:support event="onclick" disableDefault="true" action="#{action.previousEmail}" rendered="#{useAjax}" reRender="editingEmailOuter" onsubmit="ScnUtil.Status.start('editingEmailStatus');" oncomplete="ScnUtil.Status.end('editingEmailStatus');" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton id="nextEmailLink" action="#{action.nextEmail}" style="visibility:hidden;display: none;">
                    <a:support event="onclick" disableDefault="true" action="#{action.nextEmail}" rendered="#{useAjax}" reRender="editingEmailOuter" onsubmit="ScnUtil.Status.start('editingEmailStatus');" oncomplete="ScnUtil.Status.end('editingEmailStatus');" />
                </h:commandButton>
            <s:div id="viewAttachDocument" style="clear: both;width: 780px;">
              <s:div style="clear: both;font: normal 12px Verdana">              
                <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.transport.label.attachments']}" rendered = "#{action.showPopUpDialog == true}"/>
              </s:div>
               <table style=" margin-left: 135px; width: 510px;background-color: white;">
              <thead>
                 <tr>
                    <th style="color: lightslategrey;text-align: left;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.tender.confirmation.include.documents']} " rendered = "#{action.showPopUpDialog == true}"/>
                    </th>
                    <th style="color: lightslategrey;text-align: left;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.tender.confirmation.documentId']}" rendered = "#{action.showPopUpDialog == true}"/>
                    </th>
                    <th style="color: lightslategrey;text-align: left;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{labels['view.tender.confirmation.view']}" rendered = "#{action.showPopUpDialog == true}"/>   
                    </th>
                 </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                    <a:repeat var="document" value="#{action.documentDetailsList}" varStatus="status">
                       <h:panelGroup>

                 <tr>
                 <td>

                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="checkbox" id="check_doc" value="#{document.selectChkBox}">                     
                    <a:support event="onclick" 
                     ajaxSingle="true"  
                     action="#{action.getSelectedIds(document.fileNetId,document.fileName)}"/>
                    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>

                 </td>
                             <td>
                             <h:outputText value="#{document.fileName}"/>
                            </td>
                             <td>           
                                <a:commandLink  value="#{labels['view.base.button.value.view']}"  
                                 action="#{action.viewDocumentContent(document.fileNetId,document.fileName)}" />
                             </td>
                          </tr>

                       </h:panelGroup>
                    </a:repeat>
                 </tbody>

              </table>
              </s:div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the validation by attribute "immediate" set to true.

e.g.

```html
<h:commandLink immediate="true" value="" action="" />
```

Details how immediate attribute works:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MYFACES/How+the+immediate+attribute+works